# The matrix of linear operator A in other basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis

The matrix of Linear operator A in the basis  B=$\{ e_1,e_2,e_3 \}$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix}    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 0 & 5 \\
    -1 & 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
i should find the matrix of this linear operator in the basis E=$\{ e_2, e_1, e_3 \}$

I found the change matrix P from B to E
$$\begin{pmatrix}    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

thus when i calculate $P^{-1}AP$, it is
$$\begin{pmatrix}    0 & 4 & 5 \\
   2 & 1 & 3 \\
    3 & -1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

So the matrix of Linear Operator A in the basis E turned to be matrix with the change of the first and second rows and columns.

Is this right? Did i find the right matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. A 3 by 3 matrix will map basis vector $e_1$ to its first column, $e_2$ to its second column, and $e_3$ to its third column.  Changing the order of the first two basis vectors swaps the first and second rows and columns.